# BroadcastReceiver goAsync() returns null PendingResult

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a `BroadcastReceiver` in which I want to perform some work off the UI thread. As per the [example in the `BroadcastReceiver` documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html#effects_on_process_state), I first call `goAsync()`, which returns a `PendingResult`, then in my non-UI thread I call `PendingResult.finish()`.

However, I get a `NullPointerException` because `goAsync()` returns `null`.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is a simple example that replicates the behaviour. I used `targetSdkVersion 27` and `minSdkVersion 23`:

```
package com.example.broadcastreceiverpendingintenttest;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        PendingResult pendingResult = goAsync();

        AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> asyncTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                Log.i("tag", "performed async task");
                pendingResult.finish();
                return null;
            }
        };

        asyncTask.execute();
    }
}
```

Here is a simple Activity that calls it:

```
package com.example.broadcastreceiverpendingintenttest;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String ACTION = "MY_ACTION";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LocalBroadcastManager broadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(ACTION);
        broadcastManager.registerReceiver(new MyReceiver(), intentFilter);

        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            broadcastManager.sendBroadcast(new Intent(ACTION));
        });
    }
}
```

`activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.broadcastreceiverpendingintenttest.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="232dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="148dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="148dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="231dp"
        android:text="Press me"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Obviously it's because LocalBroadcastManager... It didn't set PendingResult...

Comment: @Selvin Could you submit an answer to explain why it's obvious please?

Comment: It's obvious after quick look into android's source. You have to only look at 3 places. What goAsync returns, when it's set and does LocalBroadcastManager use it. LocalBroadcastManager self is a very simple class, while normal BroadcastManager is using RPC.

Comment: @Selvin Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Would you like to answer the question and gain some reputation? Perhaps you'd also be so kind as to suggest an alternative way of performing work off the UI thread in a BroadcastReceiver invoked by a LocalBroadcastManager? If not, I'll answer the question myself later.

Comment: @Selvin, I have the same issue and am looking through the source code. It says that `setPendingResult()` is for internal use, so I'm not sure why it would be required for the dev to use it. It's a little strange that the docs don't elaborate on when `goAsync()` could return null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a `JobIntentService` instead:

```
package com.example.broadcastreceiverpendingintenttest;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.JobIntentService;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyJobIntentService extends JobIntentService {

    public static final String ACTION = "and....action!";

    static final int JOB_ID = 9001;

    @Override
    protected void onHandleWork(@NonNull Intent intent) {
        // TODO check the intent action is valid, get extras etc
        Log.i("tag", "performed my task");
    }
}
```

It's declared in `AndroidManifest` as follows:

```
<service
    android:name=".MyJobIntentService"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
    android:exported="false" />
```

`MyReceiver` then enqueues work for the Service:

```
package com.example.broadcastreceiverpendingintenttest;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Intent jobIntent = new Intent();
        jobIntent.setAction(MyJobIntentService.ACTION);
        MyJobIntentService.enqueueWork(context, MyJobIntentService.class, MyJobIntentService.JOB_ID, jobIntent);
    }
}
```

Bit more overhead than I wanted, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer here is that regular broadcasts instead of local ones should be used:

```
val broadcast = Intent("my.intent.action")
broadcast.putExtra("notification", "hello")
broadcast.putExtra("payload", 4946)
activity?.sendBroadcast(broadcast)
```

However I've also noticed attaching a debugger to read the pending result value was incorrectly saying it was null. So in this instance I wouldn't trust the debugger either.